# CakePHP 3 - How to make routes for one resource with multiple parameters

Tags: php, routes, cakephp-3.0

My Url like this:

```
/api/v2/data/:id/:id/:id/:id
```

Here, i have created plugin named ApiV2 and 'data' is resource. I am trying to create routes below :

```
$routes->resources('Data', [
        'map' => [
            ':id' => [
                'action' => 'index',
                'method' => 'GET'
            ]
        ]
]);
```

But its showing Error: Missing Method in DataController. 
I can handle this url by modifying it like :

```
/api/v2/data/term1/:id/term2/:id/term3/:id/term4/:id
```

But i don't want to use that type. What changes should i need to do in routes?. Any help will be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one:

```
<?php
// Routing code
Router::connect('/news/:slug/', 
array(
    'controller' => 'news', 
    'action' => 'view'
), 
array(
   'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'
)
);
?>

<?php 
// HTML Link code.    
echo $this->Html->link(
$news['News']['title'], 
array(
    'controller' => 'news',
    'action' => 'view',
    'slug' => $news['News']['slug']
)
); 
?>
```

If it is not working for you please let me know :)

Thanks